# Is xss attack possible between html tag while < and > are encoded

Tags: security, web, xss

Is xss attack possible between html tag while < and > are encoded?
for example:

```
<tag>{{output}}</tag>
```

if "<", ">" in {{output}} are encoded into "&lt;", "&gt;", and `<tag>` cannot be `<script>`, can xss happen?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, it needs to be said that **manually implementing your own XSS filters is almost always a terrible idea.**.

They are generally very easy to evade, especially by encoding payloads (for example, `<` can be URL encoded as `%60`, etc). It's far safer (and preferable) to use native escape functions provided by your platform whenever possible. For example, `htmlspecialchars` in PHP, `html.escape` in Python, and so on.

In your specific example, XSS is not possible with `<` or `>` because your output is inserted *between* tags and not *within* them (such as in an attribute value). Your original filter would not protect against XSS in other scenarios such as:

```
<img src="{{output}}">
```

Inserting a value of `" onerror="alert(1)` would result in this XSS:

```
<img src="" onerror="alert(1)">
```

Please do not implement your own filters if you can help it. Here is some OWASP documentation:

- [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)
- [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: yeah, i agree with the point "implementing your own XSS filters is almost always a terrible idea".... Well, come back to this question, I just want to figure out whether the jquery method text(input) is safe enough to prevent xss, which encode  "<", ">" into "&lt;", "&gt;.

Comment: it entirely depends on the implementation. if you can get src="brokenSrc" onerror="alert('XSS');" into an img then no it is not safe.

Comment: Only point I disagree with is the scope of your advise. "Implementing your own security is almost always a terrible idea".

Comment: @lwwwzh, jQuery `text` method uses absolutely other implementation. Is assigne text to thext node and browser applyes correct escaping itself.